# File with same case in JAR file on Windows

Tags: java, obfuscation, bytecode, zip, winrar

I'm editing the bytecode in one of my old projects to fix a bug, because I no longer have the source code. Everything was fine and dandy until I went to re-insert the modified class.

The code was obfuscated when we released it, so I have two files: hl.class and hL.class. hl.class is the one I'm re-inserting, but using WinRAR causes hl.class to just replace hL.class and delete the old hl.class! It's annoying and I can't figure out how to just re-insert the damn file.

[image: Somehow the obfuscator put them here, but I can't change it without the file system freaking out]

Does anyone have any insight? Are there programs that won't be such a diva about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you try a java decompiler?

Comment: Editing the bytecode was much faster in this case because I only needed to change a single boolean.

Comment: Well that’s one of the cases where you don’t get away with using a *zip* tool to manipulate *jar* files. Well, you know that each jdk contains a command line tool named `jar` which can handle jar files and does case sensitivity right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution the day I posted this, I'm sorry I forgot to respond and post it!

If you're on a Windows machine like me, I found a handy program called [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/) that's a cross platform file manager that isn't case sensitive. I managed to get the file in with it.

There's also some registry values you can tweak to get Windows to recognize case sensitive files, but I'd recommend the program I posted above to keep it simpler.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

In short, use a better zip tool. I'm assuming that you're stuck on Windows, with its case insensitive file system. Even if none of the GUI zip tools work, you can always open up a Python command prompt, which allows programmatic access to zip files, including specifying the exact filename of the content to be inserted.

If you have access to a Linux or Mac machine, it's much simpler. Just edit the file as normal and put it back into the zip. Since hl.class and hL.class have different filenames, there won't be any problem.

P.S. One other option - [the Krakatau assembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) has an option to output classfiles directly to a jar, allowing you to correctly handle case sensitive filenames even on Windows. Krakatau is also a great tool in general for low level modification of classfiles. (Disclosure, I wrote it)

Comment: Actually, it’s not that much of a problem as each jdk contains a tool which does it right, even under Windows…

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. You'll still need a programmatic solution for cases where the filename isn't valid on the host filesystem though, like classnames with more than 32k characters.

Comment: I managed to find a cross-platform file manager that solved my issue. But thanks for the feedback!